# Double -> Extract Whole Numbers

Tags: java, int, double, decimal, extract

```
int a = 4;
int b = 3;
int c = 10;
int d1 =(int) (double)(a*b)/c;
double d2 =(double)(a*b)/c;
System.out.println("d1: " + d1);
System.out.println("d2: " + d2);

Result: d1: 1 and d2: 1.2
```

How do extract/remove the 1.0 of 1.2. So i get d2 = 0.2 and d1 = 1 And
 when a = 9 -> (9*3)/10. d2 = 0.7 and d1 = 2 And when a = 6 ->
 (6*3)/10. d2 = 0.8 and d1 = 1

Thanks a lot.

Comment: how about `d2 -= d1;`?  What an odd question.

Comment: I got the solution, thanks. It was easier than I thought.

Comment: What do you mean "I got the solution"? You asked, and we all gave you the solution. Next step is to pick the best answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

```
int a = 4;
int b = 3;
int c = 10;
// Store the original value.
double original = (double)(a*b)/c;
int d1 = (int)(original);
// Get the difference between the original value and the floored one.
double d2 = original - d1;
System.out.println("d1: " + d1);
System.out.println("d2: " + d2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply subtract the integer part from the floating point value:

```
double d = (double) (a*b)/c;
int intPart = (int) d;
double fracPart = d - intPart;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int a = 9;
int b = 3;
int c = 10;

int d1 =(int) (double)(a*b)/c;
double d2 =(double)((a*b)%c)/c;
System.out.println("d1: " + d1);
System.out.println("d2: " + d2);
```